# Java ServiceLoader sometimes does not find registered services

Tags: java, react-context, micrometer, serviceloader

For our application (microservice) we're using a bunch of libraries, among others we use

- *io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave:1.1.8.jar* and its dependencies
- *io.micrometer:context-propagation:1.0.6*
- *io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.5.13* (which is a transient dependency of *com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azurte-starter-storage-blob:5.7.0*)

Our problem is with the context propagation:

When we upload files to the Azure Storage Account our imperative code uses the Azure Storage driver/libs which provide a synchronous interface but under the hood are reactive.

When the execution steps from imperative code to reactive and back the class *io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry* from the *io.micrometer:context-propagation* library comes into place which handles the propagation of information from ThreadLocals to Contexts and vice versa.

The *io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry* is a singleton which loads the *ContextAccessors* via the *Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)* which uses the *ServiceLoader* class to find all *ContextAccessors*. According to the SPI spec they are located in their libraries (*io.projectreactor:reactor-core*, ...) and there made be discoverable by the corresponding file *META-INF/services/io.micrometer.context.ContextAccessor*.

We're running our services on Kubernetes clusters, of which we have separate ones that only differ in the available nodes/nodesize: *DEV, SYSTEST, QA, PROD_EU, PROD_US*.

So far so good -  all works fine on local machines, DEV, SYSTEST and QA environment - meaning uploading files to the Azure Storage Account.

After deploying to PROD_EU and PROD_US we got errors that files could not be uploaded to the Azure Storage Account.
The error was:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context1 
at io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry.getContextAccessorForRead(ContextRegistry.java:206) 
at io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.setAllThreadLocalsFrom(DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.java:119) 
at io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.setThreadLocalsFrom(DefaultContextSnapshotFactory.java:109) 
at reactor.core.publisher.ContextPropagation.lambda$contextRestoreForHandle$2(ContextPropagation.java:162) 
...
```

In fact the error occurred in the *io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry* class where the *ContextAccessors* that are loaded via the *Java Service Provider* mechanism are being used.

To track that down we inserted this piece of code at the method where the files get pushed to the Azure Storage Account:

```
log.info("!!!!! ContextAccessors !!!!!");
ContextRegistry.getInstance().getContextAccessors().forEach(contextAccessor ->
   log.info("!!!!! ContextAccessor: <class: {}, readableType: {}>", contextAccessor.getClass(), contextAccessor.readableType())
);
```

It turned out that on PROD_EU and PROD_US **most of the time** no *ContextAccessors* have been loaded ...

Running the service on different environments gives:

| Environment |  |
| --- | --- |
| Local machines | ContextAccessors loaded |
| DEV | ContextAccessors loaded |
| SYSTEST | ContextAccessors loaded |
| QA | ContextAccessors loaded |
| PROD_EU | **On 1 pod ContextAccessors loaded** |
|  | **On 2 pods no ContextAccessors loaded** |
|  | *After some killing and restarting of pods:* |
|  | **On 2 pod ContextAccessors loaded** |
|  | **On 1 pods no ContextAccessors loaded** |
| PROD_US | **On 1 pod ContextAccessors loaded** |
|  | **On 2 pods no ContextAccessors loaded** |

Since the problem "*ContextAccessors not loaded by Java Service Provider mechanism*" **only occurs on two environments and there is not affecting all pods but only some** we suspect some ClassLoading/runtime behaviour.

But it's getting even more crazy:

We moved the above mentioned code snipped from the method to the constructor of the class which made it execute at the application startup.
This made the problem **gone away on all(!) stages including PROD_EU and PROD_US** ...

Removing this code snipped from the constructor again **let the problem appear again only on PROD_EU and PROD_US**.

This makes us even more convinced that the problem is caused by some Classloading/runtime problem.

The class *io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry* is a singleton which in fact means it is possible that each classloader has its own singleton instance. It seems by calling *ContextRegistry.getInstance()* in the constructor the point in time when the singleton is created changes which changes the behaviour of loading the *ContextAccessors*.

However, neither the point in time when the *ContextRegistry* singleton instance is being created nor multiple instances of the *ContextRegistry* (in different classloaders) should cause one of them to not find the *ContextAccessors* in the libraries which are correct published accoring to the SPI spec.

Any ideas what could cause this weird problem?

---

### UPDATE 1

I have made progress in my research: We're reading 500 messages as batch from Kafka and then processing in parallel:

```
...
messages.parallelStream().forEach(message -> {
  ...
}
```

The first message is always processed by the thread that fetched the 500 message batch from the topic (*threadName="org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1"*).

The next messages are processed by worker threads (*threadName="ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1", ...*).

Processing the messages includes pushing data to the Azure Storage Account which uses the reactive Azure code under the hood. The first time this happens the singleton instance of *io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry* is initialized which means registering all classes implementing *io.micrometer.context.ContextAccessor* by using the Java Service Privider Intrerface (SPI).

So far so good ...

**IF** this is executed by the thread "*org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1*" all is fine - all ContextAccessors are found by the SPI.

**BUT IF** this is executed by one of the worker threads "*ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1*", etc. this fails meaning the SPI does not find the ContextsAccessors which leads to
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context1*

So the interesting question is: Why does the SPI not find the ContextAccessors when called by the worker threads?

I've extended the *io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry* with some logs printing out the used Classloader, all libs known to that CL, etc. - all looks fine. Even in the failing case the relevant libraries are known to the CL ...

So it looks like a problem with the Java Service Provider Interface itself in our used JRE (java17-debian12). To check this I've upgraded to JAVA 21 (java21-debian12) but the problem stays ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research it turns out that this is the result of

- a fix introduced with Java 9: [JDK-8172726](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8172726)
- running the application with the Spring Boot classloader via java -jar build/libs/my-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I've created another StackOverflow question regarding this since it's not clear to me how to handle that correctly and this current question is too specific: [How to handle the Spring Boot classloader 'problem'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013321/how-to-handle-the-spring-boot-classloader-problem)